# Access VBA: Eliminating FindFirst Looping Duplication

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

i have 4 listboxes named listMachine, listMachineSystem,listMachineSubSystem and listcompoenents. The user selects the items the from the list boxes as he wishes and the tables are populated along with the ID from the previuos table to the new table since all the listboxes are connected hierarchially. The problem is that in the tblcomponents the seleted items get popileuted in a loop over and over agao an i dont how to stop this . I have attahced the code below . Can anyone help me out on this.

```
ID = DMax("[MAchine ID]", "tblmachine")
Dim sMachineSubsystem As String, varSelectedID11 As Variant
Dim vMaxMachineSubsystemID As Variant

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblMachineSystem", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("tblMachineSubSystem", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("tblComponents", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)


For n = 0 To Me.listMachineSystem.ListCount - 1
    If Me.listMachineSystem.Selected(n) Then
        rs.AddNew
        rs!MachineSystem = Me.listMachineSystem.Column(0, n)
        rs![MAchine ID] = ID
        rs!MO_TAG = Me.listMachineSystem.Column(3, n)
        rs!MachineSystem_Details = Me.listMachineSystem.Column(4, n)
        rs.Update
    End If
Next n

For i = 0 To Me.listMachineSubSystem.ListCount - 1
    If Me.listMachineSubSystem.Selected(i) Then
        rs.FindFirst "[Machine ID]=" & ID & " AND [MachineSystem]=  '" &   
            DLookup    ("[MachineSystem]", "tblMachineSystem", 
           "[Machine System ID]=" & Me.listMachineSubSystem.Column(2, i))  & "'"

        rs1.AddNew
        rs1![MachineSubsystem] = Me.listMachineSubSystem.Column(0, i)
        rs1![Machine Sytem ID] = rs![Machine System ID]
        rs1![MO_TAG] = Me.listMachineSubSystem.Column(3, i)
        rs1![MachineSubSystem_Details] = Me.listMachineSubSystem.Column(4, i)
        rs1.Update

        'add selected value(s) from listComponents to tblComponents
        For l = 0 To Me.listComponents.ListCount - 1
            If Me.listComponents.Selected(l) Then
                varSelectedID2 = Me.listComponents.Column(2, l)
                sMachineSubsystem = DLookup("[MachineSubsystem]", "tblMachineSubSystem", 
                     "[Machine Subsystem ID]=" & varSelectedID2)
                vMaxMachineSubsystemID = DMax("[Machine System ID]", "tblMachineSystem", 
                     "[Machine ID]=" & ID & " AND [MachineSystem]=  '" & 
                     DLookup("[MachineSystem]", "tblMachineSystem", "[Machine System ID]=" 
                     & rs![Machine System ID]) & "'")

                rs1.FindFirst "[Machine Sytem ID]=" & vMaxMachineSubsystemID & " 
                    AND [MachineSubsystem]=  '" & sMachineSubsystem & "'"
                If rs1.NoMatch Then
                    MsgBox "no records found"
                Else
                    Do While Not rs1.NoMatch
                        MsgBox "I found it!!!"
                        rs2.AddNew
                        rs2![Components] = Me.listComponents.Column(0, l)
                        rs2![Machine Subsystem ID] = rs1![Machine Subsystem ID]
                        rs2![MO_TAG] = Me.listComponents.Column(3, l)
                        rs2![Components_Detail] = Me.listComponents.Column(4, l)
                        rs2.Update
                        rs1.FindNext "[Machine Sytem ID]=" & vMaxMachineSubsystemID & " 
                          AND [MachineSubsystem]=  '" & sMachineSubsystem & "'"
                    Loop
                End If
            End If
        Next l
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) -- Sorry to say this, but this code is a mess. Nested loops doing various things with various recordsets... :(

Comment: I know but i have added the recordsets now and have tried debugging it , but i dont knwo how to chnage the code to stop the duplication creation